# Transparent background color in image

Tags: html, css

How can I **delete or make transparent a specific background color** in an image or backgroundimage?
For example, I have an image and I want remove all the white pixels in it to show what is "behind" them on the page.

```
<div style="
    background-color: #F4F4F7;
    background-image: url('wa.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right bottom;
    background-size: 200px 280px;"
align="left">
```

What functions or attributes can accomplish this?

Comment: i know can do that by photoshop but i want code in css ...

Comment: You don't do it in the CSS. You need to edit the image and make a transparent background.

Comment: Internet Explorer can handle this in CSS using the hacky [Chroma filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532982%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) btw.

Comment: It might be a little impractical, but you could use an html `<canvas>`. You could load the image into a canvas, and remove all the white pixels.

Answer (score 20):

add the below line in the css

```
mix-blend-mode: multiply;
```

You can see the background color and white pixles will go off

Comment: This actually works pretty well. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

I believe there is no javascript or HTML o CSS property, attribute  or function that can do what you are asking.

You need to remove the background in an image editor and save the image as .gif, or png with transparent background.

I use to do it with [Paint.Net](http://www.getpaint.net/) but you could do it with whatever image editor you have.

Comment: +1 for this one - I would recommend PNG format, which allows semi-transparent pixels as well as transparent pixels.

Comment: I tried both a png and gif format and neither of these allow me to insert images with transparant background that remain transparant after inserting them into my html document.

Answer (score 5):

When setting the `background`Property in CSS you can add a transparent background to the div, with the image like this:

```
#myDiv {
 background:transparent url(myImage);
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can only see through transparent images with PNG format. In your example, you are using a JPG format which does not have the ability to be transparent no matter what you do (unless you're gonna use the opacity attribute in css). Either use .gif or .png when saving an image for you to get the result you want.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I use is to remove the background from the image before using it. You can do it by running the image through `remove.bg`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can achieve this.

1. Draw your image on a canvas.
2. Remove all white (or preferred color) pixels.